# How to write a unit test on Django REST API endpoint that has permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Hello everyone I'm looking to write unit test on my django app, in order to test the different API endpoint but it seems like i can't figure our the problem here is a snap code of what i have done so far :

urls.py :

```py
path('translate/display/', DisplayTranslation.as_view(), name='display_translation'),
```

it's corresponding DRF view.py :

```py
class DisplayTranslation(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Translation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TranslationSerializers
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

and here is what I have done so far on my unit test.py :

```py
apiclient = APIClient()

class TranslationTestCases(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.role = baker.make(Roles)
        self.user = baker.make(Users, user_role=self.role)
        self.token = reverse('token_obtain_pair', kwargs={'email': self.user.email, 'password': self.user.password})
        self.translation = baker.make(Translation, _quantity=10)
    
    def test_get_all_translations(self):
        header = {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Token {}'.format(self.token)} 
        response = self.client.get(reverse('display_translation'), {}, **header)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), 10)
```

This is the error I'm getting when I run the test :
`in _reverse_with_prefix raise NoReverseMatch(msg) django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'token_obtain_pair' with keyword arguments '{'email': 'dZbQNWCjif@example.com', 'password': 'PfQzPqqVVLAdLZtJyVUxVjkGJEgRABYdHxMRhCGZJWxnZxpxEgUkgUKklENrWlBiYOCxhaDtJXdtXCtNdOJYtSWTzIrdvPnrmezXBNjEYYTpyZWjOLMnMIBMAfYnLwcC'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['token/$']`

Some more info, in the authentication on my Django app, I worked with DRF, rest_auth & SimpleJWT library.

What I could do to improve my code? or an alternative solution? I couldn't find a similar problem to mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can basically use

```
@patch.object(DisplayTranslation, "permission_classes", [])
def test_get_all_translations(self):
    ...
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object

With Authentication:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    ...
]

class TranslationTestCases(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.api_client = APIClient()
        self.role = baker.make(Roles)
        self.user = baker.make(Users, user_role=self.role)
        self.token_url = reverse('token_obtain_pair')
        self.translation = baker.make(Translation, _quantity=10)
        response = self.api_client.post(self.token_url, {"username": self.user.username, "password": self.user.password})
        self.token = response.json()["access"]
    
    def test_get_all_translations(self):
        header = {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Bearer {}'.format(self.token)} 
        ...
```

https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: yeh this indeed this work for the display test but for create & update, it don't cause on my create serializer i have this : 
   `created_by = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())`

Comment: i need to simulate the authentication others wise half of my test won't work

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one way to write a unit test case for a Django REST API endpoint that has `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)`:

```
class TranslationTestCases(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='admin@gmail.com',
            password='testpassword'
        )

    def test_list_translation(self):
        self.client.login(username='admin@gmail.com', password='testpassword')
        response = self.client.get('/translate/display/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I hope this helps!